# For some reason I cant view my state in redux

Tags: reactjs, redux, react-redux

[image][image]I'm learning redux and I'm trying to pull out values from state using useSelector hook and I really don't know why I cant see my error and loading property from state which is inside user obj. I'm also using initial state in store and when I try console log userInfo, error and loading I can see only userInfo and not loading and error. Is that initial state in store causing this problem?  please help me out ..thank you

my code

```
login.js

import React, {useState, useEffect} from 'react';
import {useSelector, useDispatch} from 'react-redux';
import {loginUser, logoutUser} from '../../actions/userAction';
import {alert} from '../../actions/alertAction';

const Login = (props) => {
    const dispatch = useDispatch();
    const user= useSelector(state => state.user)
    const alertMsg = useSelector(state => state.alert)
    **console.log(user)**
    **const {userInfo, loading, error} = user**
     **console.log(userInfo, loading, error)**


return ("<h1>welcome to login page")
}
```

userAction.js file

```
 import {USER_LOGIN_REQUEST, USER_LOGIN_SUCCESS,USER_LOGIN_ERROR, USER_REGISTER_REQUEST, USER_REGISTER_SUCCESS, USER_LOGOUT_SUCCESS} from '../types';
import axios from 'axios';

export const loginUser = (email, password) => async(dispatch) => {

    try {
        console.log('login user')
        dispatch({
            type: USER_LOGIN_REQUEST,
        });
    
        const config = {
            headers: {
                "Content-Type": "application/json",
            },
        };
        const {data} = await axios.post(
            "/user/login",
            { email, password },
            config
        );
        dispatch({
            type: USER_LOGIN_SUCCESS,
            payload: data,
        });
            localStorage.setItem("userInfo", JSON.stringify(data));
    }catch(error) {
        console.log(error)
        dispatch({
            type: USER_LOGIN_ERROR,
            payload: error.response.data.msg
        })
    }
    

}
```

userReducer.js file

```
     import {USER_LOGIN_REQUEST, USER_LOGIN_SUCCESS, USER_REGISTER_REQUEST,USER_LOGIN_ERROR, USER_REGISTER_SUCCESS, USER_LOGOUT_SUCCESS} from '../types';


export default (state = {}, action) => {
    switch (action.type) {
      case USER_LOGIN_REQUEST:
        return {
          ...state,
          user: {loading: true}
        };
      case USER_LOGIN_SUCCESS:
        return {
          ...state,
          user: {
            userInfo: action.payload, loading: false
          }
        }
      case USER_LOGIN_ERROR:
              return {
                ...state,
                user: {
                  loading: false, error: action.payload
                }
              }
      case USER_LOGOUT_SUCCESS:
          return {
            ...state
          };
      default: 
          return state
      }
  }
```

index.js file

```
import {combineReducers} from 'redux';
import cartReducer from './cartReducer';
import userReducer from './userReducer';

export default combineReducers({
    cart: cartReducer,
    user: userReducer
})
```

store.js file

```
import  { createStore, applyMiddleware } from 'redux';
import { composeWithDevTools } from 'redux-devtools-extension';
import thunk from 'redux-thunk';
import rootReducer from './reducers/index.js';

const cartItemsFromStorage = localStorage.getItem('cartItems') ? JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem('cartItems')) : []
const userInfoFromStorage = localStorage.getItem('userInfo') ? JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem('userInfo')) : null
const initialState = {
    **cart: {
        cartItems: cartItemsFromStorage
    },
    user: {
        userInfo: userInfoFromStorage
    }**
};

const middleware = [thunk];

const store = createStore(rootReducer, initialState, composeWithDevTools(applyMiddleware(...middleware)));

export default store;
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Problem is in how you are storing data in redux.

```
case USER_LOGIN_REQUEST:
        return {
            ...state,
          loading: true,  // Here you are storing loading in redux state directly
          error: null  // same as loading
        };
```

To solve this you need to store like below:-

```
case USER_LOGIN_REQUEST:
        return {
            ...state,
          user: { ...state.user, loading: true, error: null}
        };
```

You also need to change this for all your cases where you are trying to store `loading` and `error` in `user`

Comment: I gave it a try. But it did'nt work. I have shared an image aswell. Can u look into it again.

Comment: why did you update logic to return only `loading` and `error` from  `userReducer` file?

Comment: Have a look I have changed the reducer. I can see the error in my redux dev tools ..i have shared Image. But can u give me idea on how to access the error from user obj in state

Comment: In `Login` you are using `user` object from redux but in reducer you are storing `error` and `loading` in `userData` object so that is expected?

Comment: I'm quiet confused. But this is i want my state to look like. user: { userInfo , error, loading} can u look into the image i shared on top

Comment: That's why I have added answer to update `user` state of redux. So kindly please check answer again.

Comment: can u please tell me how to access these now from  useSelector hook in login page. I want to access user > user > error. I have shared an image u checkout that

Comment: In Login.js add `const userState= useSelector(state => state.user.user)` so you can access it from `userState`

Comment: I gave that a try and when I log userState it says undefined...what could be mistake I'm doing?

Comment: anyways thanks a lot for helping me out. Is there any other way you can help me out. Thank you

Comment: If you can provide some demo code link so I can help you with further. Try to use https://codesandbox.io/ or https://stackblitz.com/